# How I can get the Base64 data after converting div to img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, png

I am not expert in javascript I wanted to convert div to image then I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/)

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but how I can get the base64 data and send it to the server to save the image?

Thanks

Comment: the code you've found is actually taking a canvas and generating an image. This wont work for a div. Is it a div you want to generate an image from?

Comment: Yes I want to convert div to image, and that code works fine, do you have another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toDataURL()` to get something you can send to the server:

```
$.post('myhandler.php', {
    image: canvas.toDataURL()
}, function (data, status) {
    //Callback
});
```